# Finding Pivot element in a sorted array, How do I optimize this code?

Tags: python, optimization

Is there a way to optimize this code?
I'm trying to find an element in the list where the sorted list is rotated. [8,9,10,11,12,6,7] Here the element I'm trying to find is 6 with an index 5.

```
class Solution:    
    def search(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        lenn = len(nums)-1
        pivot, mid = 0, (0 + lenn)//2
        
        if(nums[0] > nums[lenn]):
            while True:
                if(nums[mid] > nums[mid+1]):
                    pivot = mid+1
                    break
                if(nums[mid] < nums[mid-1]):
                    pivot = mid
                    break
                if(nums[mid] > nums[lenn]):
                    mid += 1
                if(nums[mid] < nums[lenn]):
                    mid -= 1
        return pivot
```

Comment: `def search(self, nums: List[int]) -> int` - is that proper python?

Comment: Also, according to your description, you are trying to find the smallest element in the list, which is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb It is python. I know we can find min using min() but I'm trying for a logarithmic approach.

Comment: Which do you want to improve, the algorithm or the execution time? If the latter, then just using `numpy.argmin` is significantly faster, is that not enough?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is fast for small lists but not for big ones as it perform a **linear-time search**. To be faster, you can use a **binary search**. To do that, you need to use a keep a `[start;end]` range of values that contains the "pivot". You just need to take the middle item and find which part (left or right) contains increasing items.

Moreover, you can **micro-optimize** the code. The default implementation of Python is CPython which is a slow interpreter. It optimize almost nothing compared to compilers (of languages like C, Java, Rust) so you should do the optimizations yourself if you want a fast code.  The idea is to use a linear search for few items and a binary search for many ones, and to store values in temporary variables not to compute them twice.

Here is the resulting implementation:

```py
def search(nums):
    first, last = nums[0], nums[-1]

    # Trivial case
    if first <= last:
        return 0

    lenn = len(nums)-1

    # Micro-optimized fast linear search for few items (optional)
    if lenn < 10:
        pivot, mid = 0, lenn//2
        while True:
            middle = nums[mid]
            if middle > nums[mid+1]:
                return mid+1
            elif middle < nums[mid-1]:
                return mid
            elif middle > last:
                mid += 1
            elif middle < last:
                mid -= 1

    # Binary search for many items
    start, end = 0, lenn
    while start+1 < end:
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        midVal = nums[mid]
        if midVal < nums[start]:
            end = mid
        elif midVal > nums[end]:
            start = mid
        else:
            assert False
    return start+1
```